# MySQL many 'and' statements

Tags: mysql, database, select, fetch

I have this statement which is the wrong way to do it but how would I get the statement to work (the result of the statement needs to hold all the AND in it)

```
SELECT a.username, a.first_name, a.last_name
     , b.tx_time, b.account_id
     , a.id 
     , b.table_id, b.tx_type, b.amount 
FROM punter a
   , account_transaction b 
WHERE b.tx_time >= '2011-07-01' 
  AND b.tx_time < '2011-09-30' 
  AND b.account_id = a.id 
  AND b.tx_type = 4 
  AND b.tx_type = 14
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AND b.tx_type = 4 AND b.tx_type = 14` will give you empty result set. One column can only have one value at the same time.

```
SELECT a.username, a.first_name, a.last_name, 
       b.tx_time, b.account_id, a.id,
       b.table_id, b.tx_type, b.amount 
FROM punter a 
INNER JOIN account_transaction b ON b.account_id = a.id
WHERE b.tx_time BETWEEN '2011-07-01' AND '2011-09-30' AND b.tx_type IN (4,14)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use explicit JOIN to simplify a bit:

```
SELECT a.username, a.first_name, a.last_name, 
       b.tx_time, b.account_id, a.id,
       b.table_id, b.tx_type, b.amount 
FROM punter a INNER JOIN account_transaction b 
    ON b.account_id = a.id
WHERE b.tx_time BETWEEN '2011-07-01' AND '2011-09-30' 
  AND b.tx_type = 4 
  AND b.tx_type = 14
```

Note that I think it's an error using `b.tx_type = 4 AND b.tx_type = 14` because it's always false. If you need to get records having `tx_type = 4` or `tx_type = 14` you can change last SQL lines with

```
AND b.tx_type IN (4,14)
```

Answer (score 1):

I just guess you meant `b.tx_type = 4 OR b.tx_type = 14`

```
SELECT a.username, a.first_name, a.last_name, b.tx_time, 
b.account_id, a.id, b.table_id, b.tx_type, b.amount 
FROM punter a, account_transaction b 
WHERE b.tx_time >= '2011-07-01' AND b.tx_time < '2011-09-30' 
AND b.account_id = a.id 
-- AND b.tx_type = 4 AND b.tx_type = 14
AND b.tx_type in (4, 14)
```

Answer (score 0):

This part:

```
AND b.tx_type = 4 
AND b.tx_type = 14
```

ensures that you will get zero rows in the result.

---

If you want to have `punters` with transcations of both type `4` and `14`, you need to `JOIN` twice to table `b`:

```
SELECT a.username, a.first_name, a.last_name
     , b1.tx_time AS tx_time_1
     , b2.tx_time AS tx_time_2
     , a.id 
     , b1.table_id AS table_id_1, b1.tx_type AS tx_type_1, b1.amount AS amount_1 
     , b2.table_id AS table_id_2, b2.tx_type AS tx_type_2, b2.amount AS amount_2 
FROM punter a
  JOIN account_transaction b1
    ON b1.account_id = a.id 
  JOIN account_transaction b2
    ON b2.account_id = a.id 

WHERE b1.tx_time >= '2011-07-01' 
  AND b1.tx_time < '2011-09-30' 
  AND b1.tx_type = 4

  AND b2.tx_time >= '2011-07-01' 
  AND b2.tx_time < '2011-09-30' 
  AND b2.tx_type = 14
```